# Navigating with router.navigate not working with nativescript-tab-navigation template

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I have all my routes set up properly and am not getting any sort of error. When the first tab loads, I am trying automatically navigate to the second tab depending on if they are logged in or not.

**tabs-routing.module.ts file:**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

import { TabsComponent } from "./tabs.component";
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './account/auth/auth.component';
import { AddComponent } from './add/add.component';
import { PantryComponent } from './pantry/pantry.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: TabsComponent, children: [
      {path: 'pantry', component: PantryComponent},
      {path: 'add', component: AddComponent},
      {path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, children: [
        {path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent}
      ]}
    ]},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class TabsRoutingModule { }
```

**pantry.component.ts file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

require( "nativescript-localstorage" );

@Component({
    selector: "pantry",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./pantry.component.html"
})
export class PantryComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router : Router, private realRouter: NativeScriptRouterModule) {
        /* ***********************************************************
        * Use the constructor to inject services.
        *************************************************************/
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        /* ***********************************************************
        * Use the "ngOnInit" handler to initialize data for the view.
        *************************************************************/

        var loggedIn = sessionStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
        if(loggedIn == 'true'){
          console.log(loggedIn);
        }
        else{
          console.log(loggedIn);
          this.router.navigate(['/tabs/add']);
        }
    }
}
```

this does nothing. why is it not navigating to the AddComponent?

Comment: I'm also getting similar issue with router.navigaotr(), after login it's not navigating to other page, did you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you replace `this.router.navigate(['/tabs/add'])` with `this.router.navigate(['/add'])`

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue and try many path but not work. There is any work around to navigate from tab to other tab.
Beside, Manually change tabs work well.